# NService Bus 3.2 - Custom IManageMessageFailures and SLR

Tags: nservicebus

Is anyone able to help me with the following query:

I have been looking at configuring my own error handling by creating an implementation of IManageMessageFailures.

However, after spending a little time with the ErrorHandlingSample provided with NServicebus 3.2 configuring custom error handling disables Second Level Retries (as stated in the comments).

Does anyone know:
  1. Why this is so?
  2. Is it possible to configure custom error handling and enable SLR?

I'm fairly new to NSB so apologies if I have missed something obvious.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 3):

SLR hooks into the default faultmanager that is the reason that you can't combine it with your own implementation.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for letting me know.  I'll weight up the need for custom error handling over SLR.